# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "balanceOf" or "blances"?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create my own token using Solidity on Remix Ethereum. I use MetaMask and logged in Binance Smart Chain Testnet . But when I use Solidity Compiler to compile, it keeps showing this error on lines 15, 19, 24, 25, 33, 34:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "balanceOf" or "blances"?
```

Here the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract MyTestToken {
   mapping(address => uint) public blances;
   mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
   uint public totalSupply = 1000000000000 * 10 ** 18;
   string public name = "MyToken Test";
   string public symbol = "TKNT";
   uint public decimals = 18;
   
   event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
   event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
   
   constructor () {
       balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
   }
   
   function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
       return balances[owner];
   }
   
   function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
       require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
       balances[to] += value;
       balances[msg.sender] -= value; 
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
       return true;
   }
   
   function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
       require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
       require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
       balances[to] += value;
       balances[from] -= value;
       emit Transfer(from, to, value);
       return true;
   }
   
   function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
       allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
       emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
       return true;
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by a typo in your code. Rename the mapping `blances` to `balances`.

```
mapping(address => uint) public blances;  // original code
```

```
mapping(address => uint) public balances;  // corrected
```

Comment: LOL thank you, I really don't understand why I could make such a dumb mistake :(